# Unable to submit form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have 2 models, called instructor and request associated together. I would like to submit a request which belongs to an instructor but getting the  following error on the console. Can somebody help me?. Thanks,

```
Processing by RequestsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"SaLDbXaZOy2cvGILrC9IJ7vInkF0xG42bf84k3IcDj+eFN9lTRfZlkGUMr8s82zQEdO9dgJ3Set935RGH8uv9w==", "request"=>{"name"=>"dsada", "email"=>"dsadas", "phone"=>"sadsadd", "message"=>"sadsa"}, "commit"=>"Create Request"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
No template found for RequestsController#create, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 38ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

The request form

```
    <hr>
<%= simple_form_for([@request, @instructor.requests.build], :url =>{ :controller =>"requests",
                                              :action => "create" }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name, label: "Your name" %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.input :phone, label: "Phone number" %>
  <%= f.input :message, as: :text %>
  <br>
  <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
<% end %>
<br>
<br>
```

requests controller

```
    class RequestsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if params[:search].present?
      @instructors = Instructor.near(params[:search], 50)
    else
      # Shows all listed instructors by the created date.
      @instructors = Instructor.order('created_at DESC')
    end
  end

  def show
    @instructor = Instructor.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @request = Request.new(request_params)

    if @request.save
      redirect_to "root"
    end
  end

  private

  def request_params
    params.require(:request).permit(:name, :email, :phone, :message)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If your requests controller is nested under instructor you probably meant:

```
simple_form_for([@instructor, @instructor.requests.build], ...
```

Also it's very common for these controllers to have a:

```
@instructor = Instructor.find(params[:id])
@request = @instructor.requests.new(request_params)
if @request.save
  # ...
```

Remove the `:url =>{ :controller =>"requests", :action => "create"` its redundant, the form builder should figure that out from `[@request, @instructor.requests.build]`

If the `@request` is saved, you are redirecting to root_path, but you aren't doing anything if the requests fails (which seems to be the case), it's also common to `render "new"` in this cases. See sample controller in the guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters.

Ultimately you can change this default behavior, but I recommend you start with the basics and change it once you know how it works.

Comment: I actually forgot to indent requests routes under the instructors!

Comment: Not sure how to submit to this route? 
      instructor_requests POST   /instructors/:instructor_id/requests(.:format)     requests#create

Comment: I'm sorry for not posting enough info. Please take a look at the on github https://github.com/FaisalFehad/instructor_finder

Comment: You are already submitting to that route; the problem, I believe, is responding when `@request` didn't save.

Answer (score 0):

Your model is invalid, so it doesn't redirect (because `save` returns `false`). So You need to rewrite `update` action:

```
def create
  @request = Request.new(request_params)

  if @request.save
    redirect_to "root"
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

**Update:**

You use Rails 5.0, so if you declare `belongs_to` it also adds presence validation for foreign key. So, you need to create request object this way:

```
@request = Instructor.find(params[:instructor_id]).requests.build(request_params)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why its returning false?. Also still getting the    (0.1ms)  begin transaction
 (0.1ms)  rollback transaction

Comment: I do not see your model, so cant say what validations it has. Can guess, `dsadas` is not valid email

Comment: I didn't have any validations yet! its only (request)   belongs_to :instructor and (instructor)   has_many :requests

Comment: I'm sorry for not posting enough info. Please take a look at the on github github.com/FaisalFehad/instructor_finder

Comment: @Faisal after reviewing your code I added Update section in my answer.

Comment: I have changed it as you advised but it looks like its using the create action on the Instructors_controller instead of the requests_controller for some reason!. So no luck. Thanks a lot for reviewing the code BTW